# Как посадить сайт на движок?

Tags: cms

Что значит "посадить сайт на движок"? Я так понимаю, предполагается использование CMS. Но как это сделать, в особенности интересует MODx, может есть какие-то примеры?

Answer (score 4):

Посадить на движок означает, что с сайтом нужно произвести некоторые операции, которые позволят пользоваться неизменным или почти неизменным контентом на новом движке.

Comment: Какие конкретно?

Comment: Вставка php кода, к примеру...

Answer (score 2):

Если нужен именно MODx то вот почитай [документацию](http://www.modx-cms.ru/dokumentatsiya.html)

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего Вам стоит научиться функциям php и javascript.
Попробуйте сделать одну страницу(допустим главную), но чтобы в зависимости от нажатой кнопки, выходил особенный контент.

Сделайте управление своим сайтом через этот же сайт, чтобы для добавление пользователя или чего-либо Вам не приходилось лезть в код и менять там что-то вручную.

Если Вы не знакомы с php, то готов ответить на другие вопросы.

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас уже есть сайт, предстоит сделать следующее:

1. отделить вёрстку - HTML и CSS от скриптов
2. настроить локальный web-сервер для разработки
3. установить CMS (MODx, Wordpress, Joomla...) - на соответствующих сайтах есть руководства, как это сделать, в т.ч. и про локальный сервер, но если возникнут трудности, задавайте оформленные вопросы здесь.
4. заменить стандартные шаблоны темы на вашу вёрстку
5. залить всё на хостинг посредством FTP или другим способом - об этом читайте в руководстве к вашему хостингу

Answer (score 1):

Посадить сайт на движок означает следующее:

1. У вас уже есть сайт с версткой или движком
2. Вам нужно перенести это на движок, скажем wordpress
3. Вы переносите сначала верстку(Footer,Header,Content)
4. Переносите модули, плагины, которые были в старом решении
5. Делаете админку для них, если требуется